# magnification of a 3D image in a curved mirror

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, geometric-optics

[image]

I was just thinking on this  case for a 3D object in front of the mirror, 
Is there any way we can comment on its image , magnification...? 
I missed the dimensions, the wire has a base of 10 cm, and two poles of 5 cm.
Also, paraxial approximations are valid..
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Regardless of whether this is formal homework or just idle curiosity, you should read carefully our [guidelines for questions based on homework and exercise problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714). In particular, it's not clear why you specify that the image needs to go out of the plane; if the mirror is spherical (the only reasonable conclusion from your specifications) then you can just choose an analysis plane that includes the image, which brings your question squarely within the domain of textbook analyses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For objects which are relatively small such that the paraxial approximation applies (ie object height much less than focal distance), the **lateral magnification** $m=-v/u$ is the same in all directions perpendicular to the principal axis (PA). (Here $u, v$ are object and image distances from the mirror.) However, the **longitudinal magnification** along the principal axis PA is $m^2$.

So for example, for a box-shaped object (rectangular prism) with dimensions 3 x 4 x 2 cm (ie 3 cm x 4 cm perpendicular to the PA and 2 cm along the PA) located at a position where $m=2$, the image is also box-shaped with dimensions 6 x 8 x 8 cm.